Save arrangement of Map views in QGIS
I work in the remote sensing sector, and regularly process time series of satellite images, that I arrange in multiple map view windows docked around the main image - sometimes 20 map views or even more. Unfortunately, the arrangement of the map views is not saved when the project is closed; when it is reopened, the map views are docked on the same side, but in a different order and size. It currently takes me a good 10 minutes to sort the map views, adjust their size and adjust the scale again.
Does anyone know a way to save the arrangement and size of the views?
QGIS tutorials and other guides don't really delve into this matter, and all i can find are instructions how to set up the Views, but nothing about saving or restoring.
It's not necessarily about the 10 minutes, but more about the fact that it's annoying and we all have this problem several times a day in a team of around 15 people.
We use QGIS 3.28.

Adding to the Answer from @Aquamarine:
To adjust the size of each map view in one docking area, it is unfortunately not sufficient to set the width of each map view to a certain size. QGIS seems to load each map view on its own, and then adjusts the soze to fit the screen. When loading the next Map view, the size of the previous ones is reduced in order to fit the new view.

To achieve this, I had to give each consecutive map view a smaller size. I work on a 1920px wide screen with the layers window at the side, so I used the following values, which are 1800/n with n being the number of the map view:
<mapViewDocks>
<view showCursor="1" scaleFactor="1" width="1800" height="435" area="4" y="98" floating="0" name="Map 2" scaleSynced="1" zoomSelected="0" synced="1" showLabels="1" showExtent="0" x="266"/>
<view showCursor="1" scaleFactor="2" width="900" height="435" area="4" y="98" floating="0" name="Map 4" scaleSynced="1" zoomSelected="0" synced="1" showLabels="1" showExtent="0" x="688"/>
<view showCursor="1" scaleFactor="4" width="600" height="435" area="4" y="98" floating="0" name="Map 1" scaleSynced="1" zoomSelected="0" synced="1" showLabels="1" showExtent="0" x="1099"/>
<view showCursor="1" scaleFactor="8" width="450" height="435" area="4" y="98" floating="0" name="Map 3" scaleSynced="1" zoomSelected="0" synced="1" showLabels="1" showExtent="0" x="1518"/>

However, there are some constraints:

Opening the *.qgs file in QGIS, and saving it again as *.qgz seems to mess this up again
This does not seem to work properly when also using the docking areas at the side, probably due to the way QGIS loads these areas.
It somehow also changed the scaleFactor in the final project, and I could not find a solution how to properly save it without messing up the sizes again

So I found a solution for the order in which the map views appear, but the question on how to properly adjust (and save) the size and scale factor remains

I have never used map view windows, but, what about creating a layout with all your needed views? You can always lock the contents and the display for each of them.

Editing the view widths as you have done works well.  I haven't had any issues with saving the .qgs file as .qgs.  However, saving it directly as a qgz file does not seem to retain the edited view widths - one way around this is in file explorer, to move the qgs file (with the widths from 1800 to 450)  into the qgz zip file.  That worked for me.

I have tested it a bit more - and every time you save it from QGIS, the widths are reset.  If you have the file open in a text editor at the same time, such as visual studio, you can see the values change after a save in QGIS.  This means that each time you make changes to the project file, you would need to edit the width values.  Not ideal!

You can edit the positions of Map Views on the canvas manually by editing the qgs XML file itself.  A qgz project file is a zip file that contains a qgs file.  The qgs file can be extracted and edited in a text editor.
The positioning of docked windows is stored within the tag mapViewDocks.  The position of a docked view is relative to the main canvas and is divided into 4 areas.
1: Left dock area.
2: Right dock area.
4: Top dock area.
8: Bottom dock area.
Each map view has a corresponding line within the tag mapViewDocks. Here is an example:
  <mapViewDocks>
    <view zoomSelected="0" y="173" width="701" showLabels="1" synced="0" floating="0" x="1219" showCursor="1" name="Spain" area="2" scaleFactor="1" height="1101" showExtent="0" scaleSynced="0"/>
  </mapViewDocks>

You can see that you have attributes for the position (x and y) and size (height and width).  There is also an attribute area for where, with reference to the main canvas, the view is located - left, right, top or bottom. In this example the attribute has a value of "2" indicating it is on the right hand side of the main canvas:

If you add a docked view on top of this 1st one it will look like this:

But re-open the file and it will be placed below:

From testing this a bit, it seems that the order of the views in the XML file's mapViewDocks tag, determines where within one of the 4 zones (right,left,top, bottom) the view is placed when the file is opened and the Y coordinate is secondary in deciding where the view goes.
A bit more testing may give further insight.
Conclusion - if you keep a copy of this tag with the correct order of views, you can edit the project file so that views open in their desired location.
Hope this helps!

I'm new to this kind of forum, you partially answered my question so I added some own research to my question, and stated that I'm still looking for a solution. Is the way I did that alright? And should I keep your answer marked as accepted?
